# Setting priority as PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY in the LocationRequest keeps GPS on indefinitely

Tags: android, gps, android-location, google-api-client

I am using `GoogleApiClient` to track user location every 30 secs inside a `Service`, I want accurate location points as my **app** depends on it so I used `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`, however this setting keeps the GPS on for the entire duration of my `Service`, the GPS icon only goes away after I call `removeLocationUpdates` explicitly.

I want to do the following; in `onLocationChanged` callback get the location and send it to server and put GPS to sleep until the next 30 secs elapse (I think I might be able to save some battery during this period) but I do not see any way to do this in a reasonable way as there are no callbacks provided in `LocationRequest` class.

Am I missing something here or is this how this API was designed?

Answer (score 1):

> this setting keeps the GPS on for the entire duration of my Service, the GPS icon only goes away after I call removeLocationUpdates explicitly.

That behavior is up to the implementers of Play Services.

> I think I might be able to save some battery during this period

The Google engineers responsible for this portion of Play Services apparently disagree. For example, it takes a while for GPS to start receiving fixes, as it waits to receive signals from satellites. Perhaps the Google engineers decided that, for `setInterval(30000)` (my interpretation of "every 30 secs"), it did not make sense to release the GPS radio and re-acquire it.

Note that Play Services takes the accelerometer into account. Hence, the behavior that you see may change if the device is left alone for a while.

Also note that Play Services is handling location requests from many apps, not just yours. Perhaps some of Google's decision-making is based around other requests from other apps, with other priorities (e.g., `PRIORITY_NO_POWER`).

> is this how this API was designed?

Yes.

If you do not like Google's decision-making here, feel free to use `LocationManager` instead of Play Services.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After reading this I set the interval to 15 mins and waited for whole duration to see if GPS goes off. It stays on for the entire duration again.

Comment: I am exploring another option where I disconnect from GoogleApiClient in onLocationChanged and start a 30 sec timer; at the end of which I reconnect it again. Apparently this is switching off the GPS module. Will this cause any problems? BTW, the accuracy being reported is in the range of 12-20 metres.

Comment: @ArifNadeem: "Will this cause any problems?" -- I have no idea, other than you will get your fixes less frequently than every 30 seconds, as it takes time for GPS to acquire a fix.

Comment: Other problems: switching on and off each 30s is a bad idea. I expect a raised battery consumption. Just measure it. How many hours you can run your app with fill GPS (mine runs > 8h), and now test your solution with 30s on and off.

Answer (score 1):

The Api is correct designed, it makes no sense to switch off and on the GPS signal for such a short period of 30s.
The GPS chip needs the most processing power for calculating the initial position. (Thats the reason why some few cripples Android phones cannot receive an intial position without internet connection. These phones have special crippled GPS chips that, are not able to calculate the initial position).

So your 30s on/off most probably would consume more battery than leaving it on all the time.

Its always an advantage if you have  the control over your app, so think twice whether you need  Google Play Service to get locations.
And don't forget, if there are others App running and accessing the GPS chip, the chip is not switched off by the OP System.

If you are unsure which on-off intervall make sense, measure it:
How many hours your app can run with enabled GPS all the time (mine at ios 8h) and how many with 30s switch on and off.
Feel free to post the results as an self answer later.

Comment: So without switching GPS on/off, my phone lost 11 percent battery over a duration of 15 hours, the total time the application used the GPS was just over 4 hours which is pretty impressive.

The results may have been different if I was moving around all the time.

I will do a similar test tonight with GPS on/off and post the results.

Thanks for your answer.